# $f: \prod_{i \geq 1} \{0,1,2,3\} \rightarrow \prod_{i \geq 1} \{0,2\}$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, product-space

We view $X = \{0,1,2,3\}$ as a topological space equipped with the discrete topology.

$f: \prod_{i \geq 1} X \rightarrow \prod_{i \geq 1} \{0,2\}$ is a homeomorphism.

So f maps a sequence $(a_{i})_{i \geq 1}$ to another sequence $(b_{j})_{j \geq 1}$ with each $a_{i} \in \{0,1,2,3\}$ and each $b_{j} \in \{0,2\}$.

But I don't know how to construct such a homeomorphism f. If I send all the $a_{i}$ to $0$ if j is odd and to $2$ if j is even, then it's not a bijection I think.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*. $4=2\times2$. $\qquad$ :-)

Comment: You mean $a_{i}$ has four possibilities in the domain: $\{0,1,2,3\}$. And the range 2: $\{0,2\}$? 
The main thing I don't understand is the notation. For example if I say: 

$$f(a_{i}) = \begin{cases} 0 \hspace{5mm} \mbox{if $a_{i} = 0$ and i is even} \\ 2 \hspace{5mm} \mbox{if $a_{i} = 2$ and i is even} \\ 0 \hspace{5mm} \mbox{if $a_{i} = 1$ and i is odd} \\ 2 \hspace{5mm} \mbox{if $a_{i} = 3$ and i is odd} \end{cases}$$                                  This could work I think. But then I don't have a function from one sequence to another sequence.

Comment: Call $X=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and $Y=\{0,2\}$. My hint is that $X\cong Y\times Y=Y^2$ are homeomorphic. Can you use that to show for instance $X^2\cong Y^4$? What about $X^3\cong Y^6$?

Comment: Then, $X^{2} = X \times X \cong Y^{2} \times Y^{2} = Y^{4}$. And $X^{3} = X^{2} \times X \cong Y^{4} \times Y^{2} = Y^{6}$.

Comment: True. Pick a homeomorphism $X\to Y^2$. Can you then write down explicitly a homeomorphism $X^3\to Y^6$?

Comment: It' s already solved with your hints. I did send ($a_{1},a_{2}$) to $a_{1} + \frac{1}{2} a_{2}$ to prove that $Y^{2} \rightarrow X$ is a homeomorphism. And then I took de product over all i. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Both are homeomorphic to the countable Cantor cube, as they are compact metric zero-dimensional and have no isolated points.